# Is Controller a special kind of Indirection in GRASP Design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, controller

This is **Indirection** according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#:%7E:text=Assign%20the%20responsibility%20to%20an%20intermediate%20object%20to%20mediate%20between%20other%20components%20or%20services%20so%20that%20they%20are%20not%20directly%20coupled.)

> Assign the responsibility to an intermediate object to mediate between other components or services so that they are not directly coupled.

**Controller** seems to do this exactly, except that it is concerned with UI and Input events, while Indirection is more general. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, Controllers are a good example of Indirection -- indeed, the page you linked to even identifies it as such:  *"The indirection pattern supports low coupling and reuses potential between two elements by assigning the responsibility of mediation between them to an intermediate object. An example of this is the introduction of a controller component for mediation between data (model) and its representation (view) in the model-view-controller pattern. This ensures that coupling between them remains low."*

Comment: @BenCottrell 